# Dev tools - are the Errors in dev tools critical?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I highly appreciate anyone who is consider helping me.

I am working with wordpress, and once I go to devtools - in one of the theme I use, there are a lot of errors.

"Issues detected. The new Issues tab displays information about deprecations, breaking changes and other potential problems."

How critical is this?
Should I give it a large meaning, or it is not so critical.

the website is working ok tho, but I am afraid that all those errors are affecting me in a way I don't quite understand (website speed, etc).

(I am new to coding and to stack overflow as well.)

Thank you !!

Comment: It depends on the error.

Comment: You would be better off researching each error individually.  There's no way to know how critical "some errors" are.

Comment: @wOxxOm 
woo-floating-bar.min.js?ver=1.8.9:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (woo-floating-bar.min.js?ver=1.8.9:1)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3)

This is the main one that repeating it self.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with that plugin. If it behaves normally you can ignore it. Otherwise, debug the problem or report to the author of the addon or theme.